# How to implement dynamic module (in header files) loading c++

Tags: c++, module, include, preprocessor-directive

I want to load various header files (modules, plugins) depending on defines. Heres my approach:

```
template<typename T = float>
class container {
   T *_data;

 #ifdef mymodule1
 #include mymodule1
 #endif

...}
```

Mymodule1.h:

```
container<T> fooOnContainer() [maybe const] {
   makesomething involving the T template parameter
}
```

And in the file containing the "main":

```
#define mymodule1 "mymodule1.h"
#include "container.h"
in main { using it }
```

So basically only the defined header files would be included into my container. I've seen this approach in the library called "cimg" but i can't make it work, because the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter. It's fine if i make something like:

```
container<T>& fooOnContainer(T param) {
...
}
```

But is there a way to do this like in the first "mymodule1.h"? Maybe with operator overloading? Or can someone suggest me a better and simple approach if it's impossible to do? (I really don't understand how is it working for that library :) )

Edit:

Sorry if i was indefinite, so here is some code:

This is a pointless example, but i want to make something like this, but of course more complicated:

Mymodule1.h:

```
int getWidth() const {
    return (*this)._width;
}
```

and intellisense says:
   " a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function "

Another example:

```
T getPos(int x) const {
    T* px;
    return _data[x];
}
```

and intellisense says:
   "T" is undefined, identifier "_data" is undefined

Comment: How are you [`using it`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26241935/edit) actually?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also please include any and all errors you have.

Comment: eg.:
container<> img;
...load image...
container<> dest;
dest = image.fooOnContainer([threshold value or something])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, so you're only getting errors from intellisense? Not from the actual compiler? That's because the editor doesn't have all the data when you edit the `Mymodule1.h` file, the editor doesn't know that the code is actually a part of a bigger class.

Solutions? None really, if you want to continue using header files like that. The only solution is to not use header files, but use preprocessor conditions around actual code instead.

Comment: Well seems like it's intellisense only, i am an idiot :) (i got compiling errors before, but after that i trusted intellisense and didn't compile it...)

I guess i'll try to use preprocessor conditions to get rid of thoose errors in my .h files or something like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's similar to include guard and should be using `#ifndef` instead `#ifdef`</strike>

```
...
#ifndef mymodule1
#include mymodule1
#endif
...
```

The thing here is that compiler replaces #include "a.h" with the content of a.h file. No metter what it contains. If syntax in current context is correct then it should be all good.

I've tried your code and everything worked fine. So please provide detailed information about errors.

Comment: I think the OP actually only wants to include the file if the macro *is* defined, not the other way around.